# Trouble parsing two dates to query in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

OK, I have a datagrid that displays data from all dates.  I want to display selected dates.
If I code it like this it works:

```vb
Me.MyTableAdapter.BETWEENDates(Me.MyDBDataSet.FIxLastTime, ("01/01/2013", "31/12/2013")
```

What I want is to assign the dates to a variable like this:

```vb
If ListBox2.Text = "2006" Then
   Dim Yrone As DateFormat
   Yrone = "01/01/2006" & "," & "31/12/2006"
   Me.FIxLastTimeTableAdapter.BETWEENDates(Me.NewFixedDBDataSet.FIxLastTime, (Yrone))
End If
```

Comment: It would help to know what BETWEENDates is expecting as its second parameter. Or better still, what does intellisense say it's expecting for each of its parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to set Yrone to "01/01/2013", "31/12/2013" then you need to add the quotations like this

```
Yrone = """01/01/2006""" & "," & """31/12/2006"""
```

In vb.net the 3 quotes with give you a string containing a single quote.

Comment: Yeah, that's what he's trying to do, but that's not what he needs to do. That second parameter to the method is an object that is comprised of two date values... which is a construct I've not seen before (which is strange considering how long I've been in this industry)... the closest I can come up with is a Tuple, but that doesn't feel right either.